# Series of different images report same width

Tags: javascript

the JS :

```
function imgLoader(imgObj)
         {
          alert(imgObj.id + " : " + imgObj.src + " : " +imgObj.width);
        }
```

the html :

```
<img id="img_1" src="image_1.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_2" src="image_2.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_3" src="image_3.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_4" src="image_4.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_5" src="image_5.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
```

related css (updated bc of css comment / question)

```
img {position:relative; height: 46px; display: inline-block; cursor:pointer; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;}
```

note there is no other css. 
Problem : is it just friday and close to the holidays that I am missing something obvious ? the alerts from the onload all report the same value, however the same function when tied to a hover - accurately reports the width.

But when this runs at initial image load time, my alert box looks like (*this is actually a fabricated order, since the order of which the images are loaded is not yet controlled and is up to the browser - but this illustrates my problem well enough*) :

"img_1 : image_1.png : 125"

"img_2 : image_2.png : 125"

"img_3 : image_3.png : 125"

"img_4 : image_4.png : 125"

"img_5 : image_5.png : 125"

This is incredibly silly because the images vary from 15px to 400px in width. What gives?

Comment: Is jQuery a posibillity?

Comment: it shouldn't be necessary. Eventually jquery is introduced for use of a deferred & promise use but that comes later. doing some code uplift and I ran into this interesting situation. I would prefer to leave jquery out of this as jquery relies on the same objects and operations as vanilla JS.

Comment: CSS is set to `125px`? Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VMVQS/), then uncomment the CSS and see the difference. *(Open your console.)*

Comment: updated the initial question to include related CSS. The property inspector also does not show width being inherited from any ancestor / css ruleset

Comment: Plot thickens - I added some mouseover / leave event calls to the same function and - it works as intended (albeit incredibly obnoxious firing 2 alerts per mouse interaction hahaha) -Initially I was concerned this was related to the cache but that doesn't seem to impede performance thereafter - only the onload event seems to produce the "125" values......

Comment: What happens if you delay the `alert()` for a few milliseconds? `setTimeout(function() { alert(...); }, 10)`

Comment: which browser are you using to test this?

Comment: @I Hate Lazy : Chrome, Safari and FF, latest versions @Lazy - delay of 550ms added via the setTimeout process yielded correct results. Weird stuff this is inline with what i was experiencing with subsequent calls.

Comment: @Bruno - FF / safari / Chrome  all latest versions ( no ie  )

Comment: @I Hate Lazy - just to completely close the loop on the CSS option - images are displaying and performing correctly, just the initial onload polling of their size is where this anomaly occurs. Im going to step away and walk the dog to think about this, probably right under my nose

Comment: Could this be a caching issue. What about adding 5 big new images that are not cached and that will take a while to download. Then you can reload the page to check if the correct widths are displayed.

Comment: @Bruno - this is a really dumbed down version of a more complex usecase. There are various states of interaction that, when the image src is modified (and subsequently back to its original src) all report the onload trigger and all are accurate values. This condition only occurs @ initial page load (and initial onload event) - thanks all for the extra eyes and ears

Comment: Any other JavaScript running that could be interfering?

Comment: Also if the javascript file is loaded at the end of the html doc and the images are cached the onload event could fire before the javascript function has been loaded. I would check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: After some thought I have decided to simply abandon this as a responsibility of the JavaScript - these images are are being aquire via a java cms API in the first place - thank you all for your assistance - I'm am goin to accept the answer given a whatever issue is convoluting this has been isolated to our proprietary environment thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code working fine on mozilla firefox and IE 6

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function imgLoader(imgObj)
         {
          alert(imgObj.id + " : " + imgObj.src + " : " +imgObj.width);
        }
-->
</script>


<img id="img_1" src="image_1.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_2" src="image_2.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_3" src="image_3.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_4" src="image_4.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
<img id="img_5" src="image_5.png" onload="imgLoader(this)" />
```

different width are shown on 5 alert boxes. in firefox it was fast and 5 alert boxes just showed so fastly one after another before clicking.so when all alert boxes are shown then the 5th alert box was on the top. then after clicking that the 4th appeared under that.

didn't find any problem. check your images if those are in different width or not.

Comment: Telling OP that it works for you doesn't answer the question of why it's not working for him.

Comment: i do appreciate the extra set of eyes and ears, but sadly this isn't a solution heh

Comment: I got widths for 5 images in alert boxes 179,282,64,100,100 respectively which are correct. check your images if those are different width or not.

Comment: per the annotations to my original question : Subsequent calls to the function in a similar manner produce correct results - its the initial onload call that produces the strange results.

Comment: Please note the comment on question - determine to be beyond the scope of js